# Show only messaging apps on "tell a friend" sharing intent

Tags: android-intent

I want to implement a "tell a friend" action, and I have this code:

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.sharefriendtext));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.sharefriend)));
```

When the chooser dialog opens, I see a long list of applications (e.g. including Add to Dropbox, Barcode Scanner, Translate...).
I noticed that Whatsapp tell a friend feature narrows the choices almost to messaging apps only (Add to Dropbox is not there).
How can I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject test");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "extra text that you want to put");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share via"));
```

Comment: Very similar code that doesn't achieve the result I'm looking for